# ScatterChart using LineMarker as ScatterStyle instead of only Marker

Tags: java, charts, apache-poi, xlsx

After building a `XSSFScatterChartData` and I filling it using the method `XSSFChart.plot(ChartData data, ChartAxis... chartAxis)`, the plot contains markers but linked by a line..

I think the problem comes from the method `XSSFScatterChartData.addStyle` which sets a `STScatterStyle.LINE_MARKER` by default.

Here is a copy of the method I use to generate the chart:

```
private void setTrainingTimeGraph(Sheet trainingTimeSheet, Sheet resultsSheet) {
  Drawing drawing = trainingTimeSheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
  ClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 20, 30);
  XSSFChart chart = (XSSFChart) drawing.createChart(anchor);
  ChartLegend legend = chart.getOrCreateLegend();
  legend.setPosition(LegendPosition.TOP_RIGHT);
  chart.setTitleText("Training time over Fscore");
  XSSFScatterChartData data = chart.getChartDataFactory().createScatterChartData();
  ValueAxis bottomAxis = chart.getChartAxisFactory().createValueAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
  ValueAxis leftAxis = chart.getChartAxisFactory().createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
  setValueAxisTitle((XSSFChart) chart,0,"Fscore");
  setValueAxisTitle((XSSFChart) chart,1, "Training Time");
  leftAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);
  bottomAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);
  ChartDataSource<Number> xs = DataSources.fromNumericCellRange(resultsSheet, new CellRangeAddress(16, 29, 10, 10));
  ChartDataSource<Number> ys = DataSources.fromNumericCellRange(resultsSheet, new CellRangeAddress(16, 29, 18, 18));
  data.addSerie(xs, ys);
  chart.plot(data,bottomAxis, leftAxis);
```

}

#### UPDATE

So adding @AxelRichter code to set to no fill in my scatter chart data serie:

```
...
data.addSerie(xs, ys);
chart.plot(data,bottomAxis, leftAxis);
//set line properties of first scatter chart data serie to no fill:
((XSSFChart)chart).getCTChart().getPlotArea().getScatterChartArray(0).getSerArray(0)
    .addNewSpPr().addNewLn().addNewNoFill();
```

I manged to get rid of the lines linking the Markers.. Finally!

But the second part wasn't what I was looking for. Let me explain it a little bit better:

When I pass hover each point in my scatterPlot there is some text which pops up (`"label/x_value"`, `x_value`,`y_value`). The value in the legend is the same as its `"label/x_value"`. I would like to set for each data point and for each value in legend its `"label/x_value"`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basing myself on the anwser of @Axel Richter.

Here is the to code used as basis:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.charts.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFChart;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;

public class CreateExcelScatterChart {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
  Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("chart");
  final int NUM_OF_ROWS = 2;
  final int NUM_OF_COLUMNS = 20;

  Row row;
  Cell cell;
  //x values
  for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < 1; rowIndex++) {
    row = sheet.createRow((short) rowIndex);
    for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < NUM_OF_COLUMNS; colIndex++) {
      cell = row.createCell((short) colIndex);
      cell.setCellValue(4*colIndex * (rowIndex + 1));
    }
  }
  // y values
  for (int rowIndex = 1; rowIndex < NUM_OF_ROWS; rowIndex++) {
    row = sheet.createRow((short) rowIndex);
    for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < NUM_OF_COLUMNS; colIndex++) {
      cell = row.createCell((short) colIndex);
      cell.setCellValue(Math.sin(Math.PI*colIndex/10*2));
    }
  }

  Drawing<?> drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
  ClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 13, 20);

  Chart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
  ChartLegend legend = chart.getOrCreateLegend();
  legend.setPosition(LegendPosition.TOP_RIGHT);

  ScatterChartData data = chart.getChartDataFactory().createScatterChartData();

  ValueAxis bottomAxis = chart.getChartAxisFactory().createValueAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
  ValueAxis leftAxis = chart.getChartAxisFactory().createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);

  leftAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);
  bottomAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_COLUMNS; i++) {
    ChartDataSource<Number> xs = DataSources.fromNumericCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(0, 0, i, i));
    ChartDataSource<Number> ys = DataSources.fromNumericCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(1, 1, i, i));

    ScatterChartSeries chartSerie = data.addSerie(xs, ys);
    chartSerie.setTitle("My Title " + i);
  }

  chart.plot(data, bottomAxis, leftAxis);

  //set line properties of first scatter chart data serie to no fill:
  CTScatterSer[] scatterChartSeries = ((XSSFChart) chart).getCTChart().getPlotArea().getScatterChartArray(0).getSerArray();
  for (int i = 0; i < scatterChartSeries.length; i++) {
    scatterChartSeries[i].addNewSpPr().addNewLn().addNewNoFill();
  }



  wb.write(new FileOutputStream("CreateExcelScatterChart.xlsx"));
  wb.close();

 }

}
```

It will generate 20 series each one with a title when passing hover and the same title in the legend. There will be as no lines between each marker. So basically it does what I was looking for.

Thank you for your answers.

Ps: In case that you want to use some labels on each marker follow the `//set data labels for first scatter chart data serie` on @Richet answer

Answer (score 1):

`Excel` scatter charts will always have line between the markers too. If you don't wants to see this line it's fill color must be set to no fill.

References:
[CTScatterSer](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/drawingml/x2006/chart/CTScatterSer.java) -> [CTShapeProperties](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/drawingml/x2006/main/CTShapeProperties.java) -> [CTLineProperties](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/drawingml/x2006/main/CTLineProperties.java) -> [CTLineProperties.addNewNoFill](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/drawingml/x2006/main/CTLineProperties.java#CTLineProperties.addNewNoFill%28%29)

And for having data labels the series needs a [CTDLbl](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/drawingml/x2006/chart/CTDLbl.java) setting.

Complete example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.charts.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFChart;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;

public class CreateExcelScatterChart {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
  Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("chart");
  final int NUM_OF_ROWS = 2;
  final int NUM_OF_COLUMNS = 20;

  Row row;
  Cell cell;
  for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < 1; rowIndex++) {
   row = sheet.createRow((short) rowIndex);
   for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < NUM_OF_COLUMNS; colIndex++) {
    cell = row.createCell((short) colIndex);
    cell.setCellValue(4*colIndex * (rowIndex + 1));
   }
  }
  for (int rowIndex = 1; rowIndex < NUM_OF_ROWS; rowIndex++) {
   row = sheet.createRow((short) rowIndex);
   for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < NUM_OF_COLUMNS; colIndex++) {
    cell = row.createCell((short) colIndex);
    cell.setCellValue(Math.sin(Math.PI*colIndex/10*2));
   }
  }

  Drawing<?> drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
  ClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 13, 20);

  Chart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
  ChartLegend legend = chart.getOrCreateLegend();
  legend.setPosition(LegendPosition.TOP_RIGHT);

  ScatterChartData data = chart.getChartDataFactory().createScatterChartData();

  ValueAxis bottomAxis = chart.getChartAxisFactory().createValueAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
  ValueAxis leftAxis = chart.getChartAxisFactory().createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);

  leftAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);
  bottomAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);

  ChartDataSource<Number> xs = DataSources.fromNumericCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(0, 0, 0, NUM_OF_COLUMNS - 1));
  ChartDataSource<Number> ys1 = DataSources.fromNumericCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(1, 1, 0, NUM_OF_COLUMNS - 1));

  ScatterChartSeries chartSerie = data.addSerie(xs, ys1);
  chartSerie.setTitle("My Title");

  chart.plot(data, bottomAxis, leftAxis);

  //set line properties of first scatter chart data serie to no fill:
  ((XSSFChart)chart).getCTChart().getPlotArea().getScatterChartArray(0).getSerArray(0)
   .addNewSpPr().addNewLn().addNewNoFill();

  //set data labels for first scatter chart data serie 
  ((XSSFChart)chart).getCTChart().getPlotArea().getScatterChartArray(0).getSerArray(0)
   .addNewDLbls()
   .addNewNumFmt().setFormatCode("0.0");
  ((XSSFChart)chart).getCTChart().getPlotArea().getScatterChartArray(0).getSerArray(0)
   .getDLbls().getNumFmt()
   .setSourceLinked(false);
  ((XSSFChart)chart).getCTChart().getPlotArea().getScatterChartArray(0).getSerArray(0)
   .getDLbls()
   .addNewShowLegendKey().setVal(false);
  ((XSSFChart)chart).getCTChart().getPlotArea().getScatterChartArray(0).getSerArray(0)
   .getDLbls()
   .addNewShowCatName().setVal(false);
  ((XSSFChart)chart).getCTChart().getPlotArea().getScatterChartArray(0).getSerArray(0)
   .getDLbls()
   .addNewShowSerName().setVal(false);
  ((XSSFChart)chart).getCTChart().getPlotArea().getScatterChartArray(0).getSerArray(0)
   .getDLbls()
   .addNewShowPercent().setVal(false);
  ((XSSFChart)chart).getCTChart().getPlotArea().getScatterChartArray(0).getSerArray(0)
   .getDLbls()
   .addNewShowBubbleSize().setVal(false);
  ((XSSFChart)chart).getCTChart().getPlotArea().getScatterChartArray(0).getSerArray(0)
   .getDLbls()
   .addNewShowVal().setVal(true);

  wb.write(new FileOutputStream("CreateExcelScatterChart.xlsx"));
  wb.close();

 }

}
```

This code needs the  full jar of all of the schemas `ooxml-schemas-1.3.jar` as mentioned in [FAQ-N10025](https://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025).

This  code works using the current last stable release `apache poi` version `3.17`.  Note: The `Chart` code of `apache poi` is highly in development now. So the code may not work in further releases.

Comment: Than you for your answer @AxelRichter. The first part of your code `/set line properties of first scatter chart data serie to no fill` works perfectly. The second part is not actually what I was looking for. When I pass hover each point there is some text which pops up ("<label/x_value>", <x_value,y_value>). The value in the legend is the same as "<label/x_value>". I would like to build for each data point and value in legend its "<label/x_value>". Any idea how to do it?

Comment: What happens if you would trying to understand what the code does? I would try `.addNewShowCatName().setVal(true);` and `.addNewShowSerName().setVal(true);` and `.addNewShowVal().setVal(false);`.

Comment: What happens when you try to understand the question? At the end I figure out what I was lookng for. Actually I had to plot each data point as a serie and set the serie name to the value that I wanted. Like that the legend and the name of the point will change. I will post the anszer modifying your code..

Comment: @Pedropablo López Amaya: Well just another user who nevermore will get an answer from me.

Comment: thank you for your guideline i just thought that `What happens if you would trying to understand what the code does?`was not the best way to explain your intensions